# HTML div in the cell - stretch, positioning etc

Tags: html, css

Have read a lot and even able to make some of this now, but not together ) Please help.
I need th that contains the caption and the "icon" that consists of one char. And I need caption to be aligned left and icon - right. In the same th. ANd they both must be in the middle of the cell vertically. And icon should be in the center/middle of the div as well. Please help. I cannot align caption and cannot align icon in their div. Dunno why, looks like html/css were invented by aliens, I don't understand that logic and how it was possible to make such a simple thing so stupidly complicated )

Here's the screenshot of what I need [image]

```css
table
{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
th
{
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0.5em;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}
td
{
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: #eee;
    width: 20em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
div.left
{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid #7f9;
}
div.right
{
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    height: 2em;
    border: 1px solid #f79;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    width: 2em;
}
div.reload
{
    border: 1px solid #79f;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: table;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <div class="left">Title 1</div>
            <div class="right">
                <div class="reload">&#x27f3;</div>
            </div>
        </th>
        <th>
            <div class="left">Title 2</div>
            <div class="right">
                <div class="reload">&#x27f3;</div>
            </div>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Some data
        </td>
        <td>
            123.45
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Have found an answer (based on your advices, thank you!!!) 
That was easy and still dumb:)

```css
table
{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
th
{
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    vdrtical-align: middle;
    line-height: 2em;
}
td
{
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: #eee;
    width: 20em;
    padding: 0.5em;
}
div.left
{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 0px solid #7f9;
    display: inline-block;
        float: left;

}
div.reload
{
    border: 1px solid #999;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 1.5em;
    margin: 0.2em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
              <div class="left">Title 1</div>
              <div class="reload">&#x27f3;</div>
        </th>
        <th>
            <div class="left">Title 2</div>
            <div class="reload">&#x27f3;</div>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=2>
            Some data
        </td>
        <td colspan=2>
            123.45
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this ?

CSS:

```
.view-table
{
   display:table;
   width:100%;
}
.view-row
{
   display:table-row;
}

.view-row > div
{
   display: table-cell;
}
.left 
{
   text-align:left;
   background-color: lightblue;
}
.right
{
   text-align:right;
   background-color: pink; 
 }
```

HTML :

```
 <div class="view-table">
    <div class="view-row">
       <div class="left">Title</div>
       <div class="right">&#x27f3;</div>                
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I don't think this helps the OP. You're putting the text and the icon in two different cells there. Then all the following data cells all need to have `colspan="2"` if they want to be as wide as the header cells now. And I don't want to be all flamy or anything, but what do you have against tables for displaying data?

Comment: Yes, I obviously need a table. It actually contains a lot of data.

Comment: As I understand, the problem is, that if not to use table, it would be hard to make all columns to have the same width. It's necessary to know and specify exactly the with of each column that is not acceptable in my case.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the icon on the right side of the th and the title on the left, you need `text-align-last:justify` instead of `text-align:center` in the th.
Please note that you also need another `text-align-last` on the div.reload, else its `text-align` will have no effect!

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
th {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0.5em;
  text-align: justify;
  -moz-text-align-last: justify;
  text-align-last: justify;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #eee;
  width: 20em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
}
div.left {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid #7f9;
}
div.right {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #f79;
  display: inline-block;
}
div.reload {
  border: 1px solid #79f;
  width: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  -moz-text-align-last: center;
  text-align-last: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <div class="left">Title 1</div>
      <div class="right">
        <div class="reload">&#x27f3;</div>
      </div>
    </th>
    <th>
      <div class="left">Title 2</div>
      <div class="right">
        <div class="reload">&#x27f3;</div>
      </div>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Some data
    </td>
    <td>
      123.45
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Or, [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/z2k4ouj0/).

Comment: Sure, I need text in the <th> to be aligned left-middle and icon to be aligned right-middle. Thank you!

Comment: Have uploaded a screenshot. Can't get `text-align-last:justify` working as I need to.

Comment: Oh, my snippet works here in all the modern browsers. What system are you testing with?

Comment: It's strange. Latest chrome using I am )

Comment: It should work in Chrome. [Here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/YlQ2U.png) is a screen shot of this very question. I'm not sure what to suggest now.

Comment: Could you please share a fiddle?

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/z2k4ouj0/) is a fiddle of the same source as the snippet. It still works here though...

Comment: I just don't understand how it can be. Here's my scrrenshot: http://dom.etogo.net/share/Screen%20Shot%202015-06-07%20at%2016.38.08.png